# Problems with Castle dynamic proxy + Ninject as DI

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, castle-dynamicproxy

I trying to build nice architecture for my project and I decided to use `Ninject` as DI and `Castle project` `dinamic proxy` to add the caching for my repositories. Unfortunatly I get a exception. Here is my code:

```
public class NinjectImplementation : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        // Binding repositories
        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UserRepository));
        var types = assembly.GetTypes()
             .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository") && !t.Name.StartsWith("I"));
        ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();
        //CacheInterceptor cacheInterceptor = 
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var interfaceType = type.GetInterfaces().Single();
            var typeWithCaching = generator.CreateClassProxy(type, new MyTestShop.Infrastructure.Caching.CacheInterceptor());

            Bind(interfaceType).To(typeWithCaching.GetType()).InThreadScope();
        }
        ...//Service layer injection
    }
}
```

So I inject not the implementation of my repositories but the proxy class of the repositories(with caching).

Here is my `IInterceptor` implementation of the `Castle dinamic proxy`:

```
[Serializable]
public class CacheInterceptor : IInterceptor
{

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        int argumentCount = invocation.Arguments.Length;
        if (argumentCount > 1)
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
            return;
        }
        String methodNameInLower = invocation.Method.Name.ToLower();
        if (methodNameInLower.StartsWith("get"))
        {
            String cachePath = invocation.TargetType.FullName + "_" + invocation.Method.Name + "_" + invocation.Arguments[0].ToString();
            CacheHelper.Get(cachePath);
            //DO SOMETHING
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

The exception I get in `_kernel.Get<T>()` method of `Ninject DI container`:

> - Error activating IInterceptor using conditional implicit self-binding
>     of IInterceptor Provider returned null.*
>
> Activation path:
>    3) Injection of dependency IInterceptor into parameter  of constructor of type UserRepositoryProxy
>    2) Injection of dependency IUserRepository into parameter userRepository of constructor of type UserService
>    1) Request for IUserService
>
> Suggestions:
>    1) Ensure that the provider handles creation requests properly.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating IInterceptor using conditional implicit self-binding of IInterceptor
>   Provider returned null.
>   Activation path:
>    3) Injection of dependency IInterceptor into parameter  of constructor of type UserRepositoryProxy
>    2) Injection of dependency IUserRepository into parameter userRepository of constructor of type UserService
>    1) Request for IUserService
>
> Suggestions:
>    1) Ensure that the provider handles creation requests properly.

Comment: Is there an inner exception?  Perhaps with a stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer on my question. The problem was that my proxy is not a type but the instance of type so I fixed it like this:

```
var interfaceType = type.GetInterfaces().Single();

var proxy = generator.CreateClassProxy(type,
    new Type[] { interfaceType },
    new IInterceptor[]
    {
        new CacheInterceptor(), 
        new LoggingInterceptor()
    });

// I'm using directive ToConstant(..), and not To(..)
Bind(interfaceType).ToConstant(proxy).InThreadScope();
```